# Numbers XLOOKUP-like, but for specific rows?

Tags: numbers

I have a simple table in Numbers that has one numeric entry per day, over a period covering about two years. Basically,

```
    B                 C
1   Date        Reading
2   2022-03-01     3515
3   2022-03-02    14837
4   2022-03-03    25522
...etc...
```

The values in column C are not unique, in case that's relevant here.

In a secondary table I have some monthly stats about the readings. By starting with this:

```
    A             B             C
1   Start         End           Max
2   2022-03-01    2022-03-31
3   2022-04-01    2022-04-30
4   2022-05-01    2022-05-31
```

I get the maximum reading for each month in column C with `MAXIFS(Reading, Date, ">="&A2, Date, "<="&B2)`, in C1 and filling down from there. Other columns get the monthly total and average, using columns A and B and `SUMIFS`. (The dates above are all calculated with `EDATE`, aside from the start date).

How can I get the date of the max reading in a month? I don't just want the max value, I want to know exactly when that happened in each month. I've used `XLOOKUP` in other cases but I don't know how or if I can use it here. If I did, I think I'd need to define the search range based on the A and B columns in the second table, but I don't know how to do that. Can I do this with `XLOOKUP`? Do I need another function here?